# Question regarding application of Tonelli Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, integration

Hi I have a question below, I am wondering if anyone would help me with it, thank you in advance!

Prove that for any independent random variable x, y then

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}F_{x} dP_{y} =  \int_{\mathbb{R}}(1-F_{y}) dP_{x}$$

$F_{x}$ is the distribution function of random variable x and $F_{y}$ is the distribution function of random variable y

If x, y are continuous random variable, this result is trivial, but in general case, I get stuck, any help would be extremely appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that, for any random variable $X$ and any bounded function $u$, $$
F_X(y)=\mathbb E[\mathbf 1_{X\leqslant y}]=\int\mathbf 1_{x\leqslant y}\,\mathrm d\mathbb P_X(x),\qquad\int\limits u(x)\,\mathrm d\mathbb P_X(x)=\mathbb E[u(X)].
$$
Thus, the LHS of the identity to be proven is $\mathbb E[F_X(Y)]$ and the RHS is $\mathbb E[1-F_Y(X)]$.
By definition,
$$
\mathbb E[F_X(Y)]=\int F_X(y)\,\mathrm d\mathbb P_Y(y)=\iint \mathbf 1_{x\leqslant y}\,\mathrm d\mathbb P_X(x)\mathrm d\mathbb P_Y(y).
$$
Since $Y$ is independent of $X$, the double integral is also is 
$$
\iint \mathbf 1_{x\leqslant y}\,\mathrm d\mathbb P_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\mathbb P(X\leqslant Y).
$$
Thus, the identity to prove is
$$
\mathbb P(X\leqslant Y)=1-\mathbb P(Y\leqslant X),
$$
which holds if and only if $\mathbb P(X=Y)=0$, that is, if and only if $\mathbb P(X=x)\cdot\mathbb P(Y=x)=0$ for every $x$.

For a counterexample of the assertion when $X$ and $Y$ have a common atom, assume that $\mathbb P(X=x)=\mathbb P(Y=x)=1$ for some $x$. Then $F_X(Y)=F_Y(X)=1$ almost surely hence $\mathbb E[F_X(Y)]=1\ne0=\mathbb E[1-F_Y(X)]$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!! The counterexample is very helpful!